# routing with specific category

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have build a foods database and a category database, AND I could get the page successfully.

```
http://localhost:3000/foods/category?id=1
```

Now I would like to add a route to this page with id = 1, how could I make it? The following does not work

```
get 'menu' => 'foods#category#1'
```

And if I would like link to it in another controller, what should I do? Simply add

```
:controller
```

does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

get '/menu' => 'foods#menu'

this will send it to the FoodsController (foods_controller.rb).
this will send it to the specific action "menu" i.e.,

```
class FoodsController < ApplicationController

  def menu
    @category = Category.find(1)
  end

end
```

Now if you want to send it to the OthersController (others_controller.rb) just change the route as follows:

get '/menu' => 'others#menu'

You should not pass an ID via routes the way you were discussing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom action within the foods controller called menu that returns the category with id=1

```
get 'menu', to: 'foods#menu'

def menu
  @menu = Food.find_by_id(1)
end
```

Or, if you want category as the action

```
get 'category', to: 'foods#category'

def category
  @category= Food.find_by_id(1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the defaults parameters for the request to the defaults key like this:

```
get 'menu' => 'foods#category', defaults: {id: 1}
```

You can also specify the output format (e.g: json)

```
get 'menu' => 'foods#category', defaults: {id: 1, format: :json}
```

This second one will respond to json by default.

Hope this helps.